# Django server unexpected autoreload

Tags: django

I have a django (version 1.3.1) server that automatically reloads when I start a different server, and I don't know why. I assume the modification time on one of the files it's polling has changed, thus triggering the reload.

Is there any way to discover what file is triggering a reload? Or any way to get (or glean from configuration files, perhaps) a list of all the files that are being polled and could potentially trigger a reload?

Comment: check your uwsgi config - `touch-reload` option.

Comment: What server do you mean by saying django server? uWSGI? Gunicorn? mod_wsgi? Django built-in development server?

Comment: The built-in development server, @GwynBleidD. I run it like so: `python manage.py runserver`.

Comment: Django 1.3 is 5 years old and way out of its life span, consider upgrading maybe?